# How to Install Magento 2.3.5-p2 in linux mint 19.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p2

Hii i am usig linux mint 19.3 i want to install Magento 2.3.5p2 in my system but i don't have a propper Guidence. Help me to install Magento 2.3.5-p2 in my system.

I want to thank you in advance. help me...

Answer (score 1):

This might help you to install magento
https://www.alpineinc.com/2020/05/how-to-install-magento-v2-3-5-locally-via-the-composer/

Answer (score 0):

u have two ways in front. one is to use composer that I think is a complicated way but true one. and the second is to download zip project of Magento from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

and then unzip it on your Linux then set your apache root directory to that place(unzipped place) and enter the defined servername in your browser and at the end start installing  step by step that pages of browser shows u.